# Word table of content has headings of same style but has different formatting in appearance

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'd appreaciate any ideas on solving this. I think it has not been covered before in the SE - apologies if it has.

In this picture below, Sections 4 and 5 (and its subsequent subsections) ought to appear with the same format as that of section 3. As you can see, it does not.

[image]

However, each level of those headings in sections 4 and 5, share the same formatting style (with spacing, tab stops, indents and so on) as that of corresponding levels of section 3, as shown below:

[image]

I've tried updating the table, and double-checking the styles of each level to ensure they match that of section 3, but to no avail.

Would greatly appreciate any help in this. Thank you.

Comment: Is track changes on in this document? Another idea: what if you copy "3.1. Abstract" heading (only heading) in the middle of fourth chapter and refresh TOC - will it show correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

### The key to this is in the TOC Styles

See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page: [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm).

It does not matter what the headings look like. That they are formatted the same is irrelevant. What matters is the level assigned to them in your TOC field and the TOC styles for said level.

Chances are good that you can reformat an errant entry in your TOC to have the formatting you want (tab settings with dot leader) and the other entries of that level will change to match.

If that does not work, consider saving a cleaned up copy of your document on OneDrive or DropBox and posting a view link to the file here. *This is [my article on how to do this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258) and the advantages of supplying such a sample.*

Comment: The question has said that the levels AND styles in the errant and correct sections both match ("... each level of those headings in sections 4 and 5 ... corresponding levels of section 3" : ie they correspond). Nevertheless, they are not displaying the same way in the TOC.

In trying to give a link to the onedrive file, deleting the middle sections between the first correct section to the last errant section, seems to correct the TOC! 

So I cant seem to share a short document containing the error.

Comment: In a copy, try deleting the middle sections (Cut them) and then  paste as plain text. Reformat using the styles. If you want, do this one by one until you find the problem section.

Comment: I stand by my answer. If you want, post a link to a document with the problem and I or someone else may be able to tell you exactly what is going on. Here is my article on the Microsoft site that tells how to do this and and why it can help. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258